# Haskell - Using State with Alternative

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative, state-monad, alternative-functor

I have a datatype that looks like the following:

```
type Parser a = ExceptT ParseError (State [Token]) a
```

As well as state manipulation functions:

```
consumeToken :: Parser Token
consumeToken = do
    toks <- lift get
    if null toks 
        then throwE OutOfTokensError
        else 
            do
                lift $ put (tail toks)
                return $ head toks

peekToken :: Parser Token
peekToken = do
    toks <- lift get
    if null toks 
        then throwE OutOfTokensError
        else 
            do
                return $ head toks
```

I'm trying to use these functions to help validate production rules in a grammar:

```
charList :: Parser CharList
charList =
    (return CharListCharacter <*> isToken (Character "<char>") <*> charList)
    <|> (return CharListSpace <*> isToken (Space " ") <*> charList)
    <|> (return EmptyCharList)
```

It seems that `isToken` needs to consume the current token (using `consumeToken`) so that the recursive calls to `charList` then deal with the following token. However, doing so means that the alternative cases will not start from the same token as the first case.

Is there a standard way to deal with this problem?

Comment: I don't think there's anything ready-made for that. You could, however, observe how [Parsec solves this particular problem](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Prim.html#try) (scroll up for explanation). IIRC the main reason it even exists there is because it's a potentially costly operation involving backtracking a lot of data.

Comment: Monadic parsers in Haskell are typically either non-deterministic like [ReadP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) (using the list monad to capture all possible parse states and eliminate them as they fail) or backtracking like [Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) (using explicit `try`s in front of sub-parsers that may consume and fail), as Bartek Banachewicz points out. The most efficient alternative is to model your parser after an LL(1) grammar when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice from the comments, I remodeled my parser to take advantage of the fact that my grammar is LL(1). Doing this meant I had no need for `Alternative`.

This is the final version of the `charList` function (with `isToken` using `consumeToken`):

```
charList :: Parser CharList
charList = do
    tok <- peekToken
    case tok of Character _ -> return CharListCharacter <*> isToken (Character "<char>") <*> charList
                Space _     -> return CharListSpace <*> isToken (Space " ") <*> charList
                _           -> return EmptyCharList
```